# Ford Bantam 160i

Tags: ford, clutch

Good day

Our Ford Bantam 160i can't go into gear after starting, seems like the selector is the problem.
What should I look for.

Kind regards
Anthony

Comment: I've heard of a BSA Bantam...

Comment: Manual or automatic? If it is manual, then the clutch may be suspect.